# Jwplayer ads bit working on React Native using react native jw media player

Tags: javascript, react-native, jwplayer

I am working on jwplayer libary react native jw media player but
Ads not running on video.I tried  every possible solution but not worked.

```
const playlistItem = {
title: 'Track',
description: 'My beautiful 
track',
startTime: 0,
autostart: false,
repeat: false,
 advertising:  
 {adVmap:"https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/adsiu=/21775744923/external/vmap_ad_samples&sz=640x480&cust_params=sample_ar%3Dpremidpo st&ciu_szs=300x250&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=1&output=vmap&unviewed_position_start=1&env=vp&impl=s&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator=",adSchedule:[{tag: 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/adsiu=/21775744923/external/vmap_ad_samples&sz=640x480&cust_params=sample_ar%3Dpremidpost&ciu_szs=300x250&gdfp_req=1&ad_rule=1&output=vmap&unviewed_position_start=1&env=vp&impl=s&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator=', offset: 'pre'}],
  adClient:"ima"
},  
// playlist:
displayDescription: true,
displayTitle: true,
file: "https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/******.mp4",
image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/techon/image/upload/v1684847047/thumbnails/hh3yjhvbny9s3kagcb0p.jpg',  }
   <JWPlayer
    ref={JWPlayerRef}
    style={styles.player}
    config={config}
    // config={{  advertising: 
   {adClient}}} onSetupPlayerError={(error)=>console.error(error)}
    onPlayerError={(error)=>console.error(error)}
```

video is working fine but ads not running.

platform:android
envoirment:

```
"react-native-jw-media-player": "^0.2.35",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.7",
```

.

looking for help.